# Complexity of the recursion T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + n ?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

What will be the complexity of the recursion T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + n ? 
I did it using the tree method and I am getting the answer as n*2^n. 
Is this right?

Comment: This sounds reasonable to me (can't check rigorously atm). For future reference, you should include your working (so there's some evidence of your work), and this would also probably be best asked on [cs.se](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) - even if for nothing but the fact they have _sweet sweet_ maths markup over there.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include both the lower and upper bounds, and a more detailed numerical test. Hope that makes the argument more convincing.

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity of this recursive formula is dependent on the input size, where each call produces a binary-tree of calls (as you mentioned the [tree approach](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html)).

Where `T(n)` make `2`<sup>`n`</sup> calls in total, you replace:

`T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + n`

`T(n) = O(2`<sup>`n-1`</sup>`) + O(2`<sup>`n-2`</sup>`) + O(2`<sup>`n`</sup>`)`

`O(2`<sup>`n`</sup>`)`

Comment: iirc this should be even further simplify-able to `T(n) = O(c^n)` since `n = O(2^n)`.

Comment: You mean that the total complexity could be `O(c^n)` instead of `O(n * 2n)`?
And if so, what would `c` be? Tnx for the upvote =)

Comment: The link you provided isn't quite the same problem - the last term is a constant `C` instead of `n`. However the end result is still the same.

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted a different answer, hinting to that link for similarity. However, I now see your answer and was between the result I posted and yours..What do you think?

Comment: Although the *assumption* that the additive factor of n would lead to a multiplicative term is sensible, I think it is a *hasty* approach. According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+2%5Ek%28n-k%29%5Em+for+k+%3D0+to+n), the upper bound function stays at O(2^n) for all powers of n in the additional term. I welcome any criticism of my working.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I was between your result and mine's, but was more font of yours, +1. Thank you for the upvote too.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we take the *upper* and *lower* bounds of this function by replacing either of the recursive calls with the other one:

[image]

We can repeatedly substitute to derive their complexities (assuming that the stopping condition is `n = 1`):

[image]

[image]

Surprisingly, there is no factor of `n`! Thus:

> [image]

---

Some numerical tests to confirm:

```
N   R(N)        T(N)        S(N)
-------------------------------------
10  1.14E+02    3.64E+02    2.04E+03
15  7.49E+02    4.16E+03    6.55E+04
20  4.07E+03    4.63E+04    2.10E+06
25  2.45E+04    5.14E+05    6.71E+07
30  1.31E+05    5.70E+06    2.15E+09
35  7.86E+05    6.32E+07    6.87E+10
40  4.19E+06    7.01E+08    2.20E+12
45  2.52E+07    7.78E+09    7.04E+13
50  1.34E+08    8.63E+10    2.25E+15
55  8.05E+08    9.57E+11    7.21E+16
60  4.29E+09    1.06E+13    2.31E+18
65  2.58E+10    1.18E+14    7.38E+19
```

[image]

On a logarithmic scale plot, all three functions show as linear, which means that they are *exponential*, i.e. `O(a^n)` rather than `O(n * a^n)`.

If you don't believe these results, I advise you to write simple programs to test them yourself.

---

> Can we do better? i.e. Find the tightest bound possible for `T(n)`?

We can make a more *general-form* substitution for `T(n)`:

[image]

We can immediately deduce `c = -1, d = 0`, by matching terms with the same grow rate (`O(n)` for `c` and `O(1)` for `d`)

[image]

We can ignore the 3 which is much smaller than the exponential terms. Dividing through by `a * b^n`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

We can discard the smaller root since it is less than 1 in magnitude, which means it would *shrink* instead of *grow*, and thus be asymptotically irrelevant. Therefore:

> [image]

You can measure and confirm the value of `b` from the gradient of the logarithmic numerical plot above: `b = 10^0.209 = 1.618...`. The bound values can also be confirmed: `10^0.151 = 1.415...` vs `sqrt(2) = 1.414...`, and similarly `10^0.301 = 1.999...` vs `2`.

Note that the base `1.618` is consistent with the bounds (`[1.414, 2]`) obtained before.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, managed to find a pen and some paper.

Yes, you're correct (although tighter bounds will exist).

I'd like to give a proof for completeness, though (not using the tree method, using a method based off substitution and reasoning that I find more fun).

We have that `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + n`. As we need to find an *upper bound*, let's make a simpler function `T'(n) = 2T(n-1) + m`, where `m` is a constant. Clearly, for `m >= n`, this function will be "larger" than `T(n)` (see footnote), so if we can find an upper bound for this function, we have an upper bound for the original one (as long as we pick our constant `m` to be greater than `n` at the time). It also has the advantage of being much easier to model!

Let's run through a bit of the behaviour of `T'(n)`:

```
T'(n) = 2T'(n-1) +  m
      = 4T'(n-2) + 3m
      = 8T'(n-3) + 7m
      = ...
      = 2^k T'(n-k) + (2^k - 1)m
```

The last equation is taken by following the logical progression to what we're looking at after an arbitrary number `k` iterations (`0 <= k <= n`).

If we now extend forward to the end of the iterations, that is when `n = k`, we have:

```
T'(n) = 2^n T'(0) + (2^n - 1)m
```

If we let `T'(0)` be a constant `c0`, then we have an upper bound for `T'`:

```
T'(n) = c0*2^n + m*2^n - m
```

Where `c0` and `m` remain constants, so we can't really do much with them yet.

Now we said that `T'` is "bigger" than `T` for all `m >= n`, so let's say that the first time we "call" `T`, we set `m = n`. That is, we've set our constant to be the largest value `n` can take through the progression. Let see what we get then:

```
T'(n) = c0*2^n + n*2^n - n
```

Which is therefore `O(n*2^n)`. Perfect!

For the final touch, as `T'` is "bigger" than `T` for all `m >= n`, and we have an upper bound for `T'`, we know that `T` must also obey that upper bound, so `T` is also `O(n*2^n)`, just like you found.

Please point out any mistakes, I've likely mixed up some letters somewhere!

Edit: Really, you'd also want to prove that `T'` actually is bigger than `T` like we said - but that's trivial and you can easily convince yourself of it by the fact one sums a constant while the other sums a decreasing series.